# The requests that ngrok receive never respond

Tags: ngrok

I have server where docker is installed and there are running multiple microservices, one is a gateway and the other one is the main process, I installed ngrok because I need to make some request from outside my server. But request that arrive to ngrok are getting stuck. I made a test and add logs in my main process and the responses of my main process seems to be ok but in ngrok shows the message:

```
The request body is still being read.
```

This is my ngrok.yml configuration:

```
version: "2"
authtoken: token
log_level: "error"
web_addr: localhost:4040
tunnels:
  omnicanaldesarrollo:
    proto: http
    addr: localhost:8088
    domain: domain1
  omnicanaldesarrollogateway:
    proto: http
    addr: localhost:8089
    domain: domain2
```

Also the configuration of the gateway is:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
              allowedOrigins: "*"
              allowedMethods: "*"
              allowedHeaders: "*"
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:          
      - id: msamix
        uri: lb://msamix
        predicates:
          - Path=/amix/**
        filters:
          - name: CircuitBreaker
            args:
              name: configuracion
              statusCodes: 503
              fallbackUri: forward:/fallback
resilience4j:
  timelimiter:
    instances:
      configuracion:
        timeout-duration: 15s
```

I thing that I need to add a configuration of ngrok but I don't know which configuration, can someone help me please?